# socket.io/socket.io.js stuck on (pending) - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So whenever I check if the /socket.io/socket.io.js file is loaded onto my webpage is says `(pending)` and after a while `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I've been looking through some other posts and trying some stuff.

I've tried using `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
and `<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

My original code includes `<script src="http://10.0.0.199:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` where `10.0.0.199` is my server which is running node.js and mongoDB.

My full code of my `server.js` file is as follows: (this file starts the `socket.io`)

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
    console.log('info - socket.io started');
```

Comment: Are you trying to import node.js script to web browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my firewall somehow managed to block the `8080` port again.

I used `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Socket.io port"` to open the port on my firewall but this did not help. I managed to open the port using the GUI on my server.

Thanks everyone, and I hope that this might help someone in the future as this was very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not try to import Node JS script on web page
2. You can not play directly with socket in JS under Web Browser. Currently web browsers support only websockets.

Comment: I'm trying to following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkXQEwHn2nA) which tells me that I should do this.. It actually does work for him.

Comment: In that tutorial that person is trying to fetch the js  from http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js not from http://127.0.0.1/socket.io/socket.io.js  It means he is using node server at port 8080 so the js file would be compiled by node js not by browser. But you are fetching it from apache server so the file is nothing but simple Js which would be directly compiled by the browser

Comment: I actually tried doing that but I forgot to add that